# Xpath how do I get the total string length of all attributes on the parent's children?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

A fairly staright foward question, or so I thought...

`select="../Store"` returns a nodeset containing all of the nodes I need. I then need to calculate the string length of the name attribute attached to the Store node.

I would have thought it would be this:
`select="string-length(../Store/@name)"` but this only returns the string length of the first node.

Any ideas?

Comment: We have no idea what `Store` element contains and how many attributes does it contain...!!

Comment: I'm only interested in the string-length of the @name attribute.

Comment: "select="string-length(../Store/@name)" but this only returns the string length of the first node." This is expected, what are you exactly looking for ?

Comment: I want the combined string length of the @name attributes on all Store nodes. Well actually I want the average, but I thought this was a good start.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<xsl:variable name="StoreNames">
  <xsl:for-each select="../Store">
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select="string-length($StoreNames)" />
```

Nice and easy!

Answer (score 9):

**In XPath 2.0 use a single expression like this**:

```
sum(../Store/@name/string-length(.))
```

**This cannot be done with a single XPath 1.0 expression** (a function as a location step isn't allowed), therefore some help of the hosting language is needed.

**For example, if the hosting language is XSLT**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Store[@name][1]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Store[@name]">
  <xsl:param name="vAccum" select="0"/>

  <xsl:value-of select="$vAccum + string-length(@name)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Store[@name and following-sibling::Store/@name]">
  <xsl:param name="vAccum" select="0"/>

  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Store[@name][1]">
    <xsl:with-param name="vAccum" select="$vAccum + string-length(@name)"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<root>
  <Store name="ab"/>
  <Store name="cde"/>
  <Store name="fgh"/>
  <Store name="ijklmn"/>
  <Store name="opr"/>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

17

Comment: amazing!! .. (xslt 1.0 solution)

Comment: flyx's code didn't work for OP, so I assume he's working with XSLT 1.0 processor ..

Comment: @infantprogrammer'Aravind': If you find this amazing, you need to have a look at FXSL: http://fxsl.sf.net :)

Answer (score 3):

```
sum(../Store/@name/string-length())
```

Comment: It should. How did you use it?

Comment: @flyx, I guess OP is having XSLT 1.0 :)

Comment: Ah, I see, this is not allowed in XPath 1.0. Your parser probably isn't capable of XPath 2.0.

Answer (score 3):

I assume your input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <Store name="data1"/>
  <Store name="data2"/>
  <Store name="data3"/>
  <Store name="data4"/>
  <Store name="data55"/>
</root>
```

Here is the XSLT code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Store[1]">
      <xsl:call-template name="calclength"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="calclength">
    <xsl:param name="lengthsum" select="'0'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="newlengthsum" select="string-length(@name/.) + $lengthsum"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::Store[1]">
      <xsl:call-template name="calclength">
        <xsl:with-param name="lengthsum" select="$newlengthsum"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::Store[1])">
      LengthOfNameAttrs:
        <xsl:value-of select="$newlengthsum"/>

      Averagelength:
        <xsl:variable name="count" select="count(../Store)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$newlengthsum div $count"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output is:

```
  LengthOfNameAttrs:
    26

  Averagelength:
    5.2
```

You need to call template `calclength` only for first `Store` node.. ie, `Store[1]` it will calculate and return the sum of all `sibling-nodes` .. just use these XML and XSLT files and execute them. Let me know if you need any help in `calling the template` part. It can be edited in accordance.